# Running "grunt package" returns "Aborted due to warnings" when building AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, npm, bower

I'm trying to get my PC setup to build Angular JS for the purpose of contributing to the project. Grunt, Bower, and to some extent, npm are new territory for me. I'm following the [official documentation for building Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute#building-angularjs) but upon running the `grunt package` step, I'm met with a wall of warnings of either "Directory not empty" or "File or path name too long" and finally I'm told that the process "Aborted due to warnings".

I'm running the command window with administrator privileges as instructed. I've done nothing outside of the steps in the documentation linked to above, and I've not touched the repository after cloning.

How do I remedy this? I'm really not sure what more to post in this question that may be of use, but I'll gladly edit and include anything that's requested in comments.

**Edit:** here's just a small section of some of the errors I'm getting:

[image]

I've tried moving the folder to the base path of the drive so that the path couldn't possibly be any shorter but I still receive the same errors.

Comment: how long is the path to the base directory where your project is stored at on your hard disk?

Comment: @Claies it's not absurdly long, the folder is currently on my desktop.